# jQuery dataTables row.add with different classes on outer td based on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add entries to a jQuery Datatable with [row.add](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) and while adding (or afterwards if not possible while adding) change the class of the outer `<td>` based on the content.
Values > 5 should get the class `color-green`, values below 5 `color-red`

```js
var mTableROH   = $('.mm-table.ROH').DataTable(
    {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        "stateSave": true,

    }
);

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  mTableROH.row.add(
          [
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
             (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
          ]
  );
 
}
 mTableROH.columns.adjust().draw();
```

```css
.color-red{
  color: red;
}

color-green{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

                            <table id="mm-table-roh" class="table table-striped table-bordered mm-table ROH">
                                <thead>                             
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Value 1</th>
                                        <th>Value 2</th>
                                        <th>Value 3</th>
                                        <th>Value 4</th>
                                        <th>Value 5</th>
                                        <th>Value 6</th>
                                        <th>Value 7</th>
                                        <th>Value 8</th>
        
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                
                                </tbody>

                            </table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

How to add those classes while adding new rows like this?

Comment: Have you tried just to wrap your new row data with a <span class="myClass">myData</span>

Comment: @Thallius - this is not exactely what I was asking for, but yes - it would work too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after reading your comment I did more research and I think this is better since I believe you are concerned about performance:

```
var mTableROH = $('.mm-table.ROH').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "stateSave": true,
    "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) { // add a callback function
        const length = row.children.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            row.children[i].className = data[i] > 5 ? "color-green" : "color-red";
        }
    }
});

// Below remains the same as my previous answer
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let randomNumbers = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        randomNumbers.push((Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2));
    }
    mTableROH.row.add(randomNumbers)
}
mTableROH.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Basically we can just add a createdRow (https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) property inside the object argument of `.DataTable()` that is executed when `a TR element is created (and all TD child elements have been inserted)`

Also another change is this time it's replacing all the classes of the `td` elements instead of adding a class, if you just wanna add the class you can replace

```
row.children[i].className = data[i] > 5 ? "color-green" : "color-red";
```

with

```
row.children[i].classList.add(data[i] > 5 ? "color-green" : "color-red");
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm at this let me also help you simplify your for loop so that you don't have to repeat `(Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2)` 8 times

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let randomNumbers = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        randomNumbers.push((Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2));
    }
    mTableROH.row.add(randomNumbers)
}
mTableROH.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Right after the above code, you can write this, this adds the class after the adding of the table cells:

```
$(".mm-table.ROH tbody td").each(function() {
     const value = parseFloat($(this).text());
     $(this).addClass(value > 5 ? "color-green" : "color-red");
});
```

What it does is using the jQuery selector we can retrieve all the `td` elements inside the `tbody` of the element with class `.mm-table.ROH`, and using the .each() function, we pass in a function that gets executed for each `td` element. So we retrieve the value from the `.text()` property of `$(this)` (which refers to the current `td` element), and then add the corresponding class based on if the value is more than 5 or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'll upvote but leave the question open for now - because the ideal solution would be adding the class while adding the row. If I don't receive any answers until tomorrow, Ill accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is an approach on how to tackle your problem. Get all your cells with `document.querySelectorAll` and then you should do a `forEach` method in order to get the innerHTML of every cell. Thus this will allow you to get the string and from there on you can do a `parseFloat()` method to get the real numeric value of the cell. At last, you can do a conditional statement which checks if the value is below or more than 5. If it is likewise, you assign the class with `classList.add()` inside every cell you need. Cheers

```js
var mTableROH = $('.mm-table.ROH').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  "stateSave": true,
   "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) { // add a callback function
    const length = row.children.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         (data[i] > 5) ? row.children[i].classList.add("color-green") : row.children[i].classList.add("color-red");
    }
}
});

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  mTableROH.row.add(
      [
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
        (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2),
      ]).draw()
    .nodes()
    .to$()
    .addClass('row');
}

mTableROH.columns.adjust().draw();
```

```css
.color-red {
  color: red;
}

.color-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="mm-table-roh" class="table table-striped table-bordered mm-table ROH">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
      <th>Value 3</th>
      <th>Value 4</th>
      <th>Value 5</th>
      <th>Value 6</th>
      <th>Value 7</th>
      <th>Value 8</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>

</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll upvote but leave the question open for now - because the ideal solution would be adding the class while adding the row.